# Rails - Events fully booked

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, mvc

I'm building an events app using Rails. I've installed a code block in my controller to ensure that over-booking doesn't occur once the total number of spaces for the event have been allocated/booked. 
The issue is that it only seems to work after the payment has been taken rather than before. I need the code to bring up a flash message when the user clicks on book the event but, at present, it allows the user to go through the payment process, takes their money AND THEN when it redirects back to the event page the flash message pops up. 
It also only works for paid events and not free events.

Here's my bookings_controller code -

```
 class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        #@total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

    end

    def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

        Booking.transaction do

            @event.reload
            if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
            end 
        end

        if @booking.save

            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            # #{} == puts a variable into a string
            Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end

        if @event.is_free?

            @booking.save!
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        end
    end

    #def total_amount
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity * @event.price
    #end

    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end

end
```

What logic do I need to apply in order for this to work at the appropriate point for the user? Also, is this logic better placed in the Model rather than the controller?

Comment: I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving existing, working code. Code Review is not the site to ask for help in fixing or changing *what* your code does. Once the code does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way! Please see our [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: Just to explain, I was recommended to put this question on this site following a conversation on Stack Overflow. I wasn't completely sure whether this was right or not but as the code does, technically, work albeit not as I want it to I thought it was still okay to post. Apologies if this is not the case.

Comment: If it doesn't work as intended, it doesn't work. Stack Overflow has been known to make inappropriate remarks, we're sorry you got caught in the crossfire.

Comment: So, where do you go if you're not getting the answer your looking for from Stack Overflow? I'm a 'code-loner' so finding the solutions (or a better way to do something) can be a struggle.

Comment: I suggest you ask one question per each post on Stack Overflow that way you don't get downvoted. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would totally separate the logic from Controller to Model to make the Controller cleaner. This way you can also test the business logic easily in unit tests.

- You don't need the Booking.transaction block.
- The booking.count should be a validated in the Event model.
- You should move the Stripe charging and testing if event is free to  after_create callback in Booking model. after_create is better than after_save, because if you would use after_save you would be trying to charge for the booking even when you would update the record, which might be unwanted behaviour.